# Get IP of Azure VM using SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management

I have a VM powered on and running in azure. I know its name but want to retrieve its IP address programmatically using the new C# SDK and avoiding the REST API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string subId = "deadbeef-beef-beef-beef-beefbeefbeef";
string resourceGroup = "SORG01";
string vmName = "SORG01-BOX01";

using (var client = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials))
{
    client.SubscriptionId = subId;

    VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachinesOperationsExtensions.Get(client.VirtualMachines, resourceGroup, vmName);

    networkName = vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id.Split('/').Last();
}

using (var client = new NetworkManagementClient(credentials))
{
    client.SubscriptionId = subId;
    var network = NetworkInterfacesOperationsExtensions.Get(client.NetworkInterfaces, resourceGroup, vmName);
    string ip = network.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIPAddress;
}
```

To have these classes, you'll need to install from nuget:

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network

Note that you'll have to select "Include Prerelease" on the nuget search window in order to find these packages. `credentials` is a `Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials` object that you acquire in this manner:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{YourTenantId}");
var credential = new ClientCredential("{YourAppID}", "{YourAppSecret}");
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", credential);

result.Wait();
if (result.Result == null)
    throw new AuthenticationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

credentials = new TokenCredentials(result.Result.AccessToken);
```

Comment: how about the public IP address? I could not fetch the public Ip address !

Comment: @k2ibegin Check `PublicIPAddressesOperationsExtensions` rather than `NetworkInterfacesOperationsExtensions`.

Comment: thanks , I also was able to do it via client.PublicIPAddresses.Get(groupName, publicIpName);

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to retrieve the public IP Address of Azure Virtual Machine is

{_VirtualMachineInstance}.GetPrimaryPublicIPAddress().IPAddress;

Very good explanation of this matter you can find here- Tom Sun answer:

[Get Azure VM using resource manager deployment and rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723746/get-azure-vm-using-resource-manager-deployment-and-rest-api)