# How to Retrieve Public IP Address and Private IP Address of an Azure VM with Azure Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-for-java

I am working on a Java project that needs to retrieve a VM's public ip and private ip with Azure Java SDK.

I find two potentially useful classes `com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachine`
and

```
com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.fluent.models.VirtualMachineInner
```

After hours of investigation, I cannot figure out how.
The VirtualMachine class only has a function to get primary public ip. Neither of them has a function to get private ip.

Did I missing anything from the two classes?

Is there a way to list all details of VMs under a subscription with Java SDK like what we get with `az vm list -d --subscription $Subscription_Id` in Azure CLI?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Example in C# https://stackoverflow.com/a/37575946/8016720 The class names are similar in Java. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.network?view=azure-java-stable

Answer (score 0):

Call (the `azure` object is initialized via guide https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/mgmt)

```
var vms = azure.virtualMachines().list();
```

Then for each of them, call

```
vm.getPrimaryNetworkInterface().primaryPrivateIP();
```

for private IP.

```
vm.getPrimaryPublicIPAddress();
```

for object of public IP, it could be `null`. If not `null`, then use `ipAddress()`.

It is more complicated as either private IP or public IP is not within the `VirtualMachine` object, but in `NetworkInterface` object (or further `PublicIpAddress` object) and need to be done via additional REST API.