# Get network interface from VirtualMachineScaleSetResource

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-management-api

I want to list all VMs in a Scale Set and print the VM name, and private and public IP using the C# management SDK. Sofar I have the following code:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;

var armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var scaleSet = armClient.GetVirtualMachineScaleSetResource("/long/id");

Console.WriteLine("vms:");
await foreach (var vm in ss.GetVirtualMachineScaleSetVms().GetAllAsync())
{
  Console.WriteLine($"  vm: {vm.Id.Name}");
}
```

The above code works and prints -- as expected -- the list of vms in my scaleset:

```
vms:
  vm: fleet-a_90f4de84
  vm: fleet-a_c439ee3c
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get the network information from here.

I expected to find it in `vm.Data.NetworkProfile` or `vm.Data.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations[].` but even though `vm.HasData` is `true`, `vm.Data` has all fields set to `null` (and `vm.Data.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations[]` is empty):

[image: vm.Data screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Using ARM client methods, I have tried to reproduce the code to retrieve network interface ip configuration(private and public ips) for the VMs, but I could only fetch Network Interface.

By using ARM client classes in C# management SDK, as you are able to get the list of vms in your scale set, you can also fetch the Network Interface using the below code:

```cs
var networkInterfaceReference = vm.Data.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id.Name;
```

By using the list of VMs and Network Interface, you can use alternate method to fetch the ip details.

Thanks to **@sridank.** By referring to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575945/get-ip-of-azure-vm-using-sdk), I have followed below alternative code to get the IP addresses of VMs programmatically.

Follow the below method to fetch ip details of vm:

1. To establish the authentication:

```cs
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{YourTenantId}");
var credential = new ClientCredential("{YourAppID}", "{YourAppSecret}");
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", credential);

result.Wait();
if (result.Result == null)
    throw new AuthenticationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

credentials = new TokenCredentials(result.Result.AccessToken);
```

2. Code to get the ip details:

```cs
string subscriptionId = "XXXXXXXX";  
string resourceGroupName = "XXXXX";  
string vmName = "XXXXXXXXX";
using (var client = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials))  
{  
client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachinesOperationsExtensions.Get(client.VirtualMachines, resourceGroup, vmName);
networkName = vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id.Split('/').Last();  
}
using (var client = new NetworkManagementClient(credentials))  
{  
client.SubscriptionId = subId;  
var network = NetworkInterfacesOperationsExtensions.Get(client.NetworkInterfaces, resourceGroupName, vmName);  
string ip = network.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIPAddress;  
}
```